# counting number of lines not working correctly through loop

Tags: c

I'm trying to count the number of lines of a wchar_t string on my C program using 2 methods: 1st method using a loop through the buffer counting "\n", the 2nd one is using `wcstok()` however I got only the 2nd method returning the correct lines number, the 1st one returns always 0: here is my full program code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const wchar_t* ret2line_template = L"\n";

int get_lines_count1(wchar_t* w){
int count=0;
int i;
for(i=0;i<wcslen(w);i++)if((w[i]==ret2line_template[0]) && (w[i+1]==ret2line_template[1]))count++;
return count;
}
int get_lines_count2(wchar_t* w){
    int count=0;
    wcstok(w, ret2line_template);
    do{count++;}while(wcstok(0, ret2line_template));
    return count;
}

int main(){
const wchar_t* s = L"00\n11\n22\n33";
const wchar_t* w;
w = calloc(sizeof(wchar_t*), wcslen(s)+1);
wcscpy(w, s);
printf("lines count from get_lines_count1 = %d\n", get_lines_count1(w)); //this returns 0: incorrect value
printf("lines count from get_lines_count2 = %d\n", get_lines_count2(w)); //this returns 4: the correct value
getch();
}
```

so what's wrong with my `get_lines_count1` function and its loop? how to fix that problem? please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only incrementing `count` in the first function if you match on a newline **followed by a null char**.

This:

```
ret2line_template[1]
```

in your conditional expression is looking at the second wchar_t in this:

```
const wchar_t* ret2line_template = L"\n";
```

which is the zero terminator. None of the pairs of wchar_t's in your string match this, so the result is zero. Just look for a `L'\n'`. If there are chars left after the last one, add one more "line" to your count (the last one that has no `L'\n'` trailing.

Comment: The string `L"\n"` is *two* `wchar_t` characters. The character `L'\n'`, and the character `L'\0'` for the string terminator. The latter you should not be using in your comparison logic.